# How to throw std::bad_alloc with a custom message in C++?

Tags: c++, bad-alloc

Since VS2008 the class bad_alloc does not provide a constructor with string parameter. Is there any possibility to create a custom message without overwriting the class like this?

```
// this is only pseudo-code
class custom_exception : bad_alloc {
public:
    string Message;
    custom_exception(string m) {Message = m;}
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify - what do you need it for? To have different messages when it is thrown from different places?

Comment: Yes, from different places of the class hierarchy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bad_alloc` needs to be constructible without allocating memory, which is why its constructor does not take a message parameter.  You can of course subclass it and override `what`.